# What is the maximum number of combinations with repetitions, that the sum could be the same?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have $n$ integers (both negative and positive) and I get all combinations of $k$ elements with repetition $((n, k)) = (n + k-1, k)$

My question is: what is the maximum number of combinations, that the sum could be the same? That is, what is the maximum number of combinations with the same amount, I can get by carefully selecting the $n$ numbers.  Assuming that two combinations whose elements were the same but in a different order, are the same combination.

I've been testing with 4 numbers selected such that an attempt to obtain the maximum number of combinations with the same sum. I noticed that either combining of 3 on 3 with repetition, 2 on 2 with repetition or 5 on  5, in all cases, the maximum number of combinations with the same sum, was always 3. I have never managed to fix the 4 numbers to obtain a larger number of combinations with the same amount.

If this were a general rule, then the maximum number of combinations with repetition that sum the same for $n$ elements, is always $n-1$, regardless of the value of $k$. Is it true?

Does anyone know where there is a general proof? Or a formula?

Comment: When you say 4 numbers selected and combining 2 on 2, what are the possibilities?  I would imagine the base set could be $\{1,2,3,4\}$ and you pick a pair with repetition?  You have $1+3=2+2, 1+4=3+2, 2+4=3+3$ are those the three?

Comment: Hello Ross. With these numbers The maximum number with the same sum is two, for example 1+3 = 2+2 or 1+4= 3+2 or 2+4 = 3+3

Comment: I can't find now combinig 2 on 2, the 3 I have said, I always find only two as the maximum number..I was wrong...Oh god, now I'm lost.

Comment: I hate when such doubts assail me; too complex to find something made by internet, too irrelevant to appear in a book.

Comment: So for "3 on 3" you would have to find three lists of three numbers that all have the same sum, like $1+3+4=2+2+4=2+3+3$?  Would $1+2+5$ (were $5$ in the set) make it 4 on 3 or 3 on 4?

Comment: In your example you have a set of 5 numbers {1,2,3,4,5} and with this numbers you find that exists 4 combinations (3 on 3) with the same sum 8. It is posible to find a set {a,b,c,d} with more than 4 combinations(3 on 3) with sum S? My question is , with a set of n elements {a,b,c...n} (negative numbers included) which is the maximum number of combinations with repetitions k on k that can have the same sum S?

Comment: I think the answer is n/2 or (n+1)/2 , and k has nothing to do. For sure someone has resolved this, but where can i find it?

Comment: I am still trying to understand what you mean by "3 on 3".  Is it selecting three elements of the set with repetition?  In that case it sounds like $k=3$.

Comment: Selecting three elements from $\{0,1,2,3,4,6,7\}$ I find $0+2+7=1+1+7=0+3+6=1+2+6=0+4+5=1+3+5=2+2+5=1+4+4=2+3+4=3+3+3$ for $10$ combinations.  How do you express it in your language?

Comment: Thank you for your interest, Ross. Yes, in my language when I say 3 on 3 I mean k= 3. In your example n= 8, k= 3 and you have find 10 combinations with the same sum 9

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $k=4$, we have $0077,0167,0257,0347,1157,1247,2237,0266,1166,1256,$ and there are many more.  Clearly the number will rise faster than $n$

Added:  you are looking for the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient).  The maximum will come when the sum is $k(n+\frac 12)$.  There doesn't seem to be a simple formula.

Comment: Your right. I'm not able to find a general rule... it is not true what i first said. It depends of n and k.  Unfortunately  computer is down, so i have to work with pen and paper. I was playing a little with n=7 and k=5 and it depends of n/2 and k/2 the way it reises